# Best Management tool for self-employed: Tasks, Calendar, Multiple Customers, Multiple Project, Invoice, Time-Track

Tags: time-management, project-management, customer-relations

I need to organize my working hours for many projects and customers due to huge work load.

I would like a web app with the following features:

- Tasks
- List item
- Calendar
- Multiple Customers
- Multiple Project
- Invoice (opt)
- Time-Track (opt)

I tried several ones, found Scoro to be one of the best but really expensive due to their min. 5 users policy, also Humanity and others are cute but not complete.

Actually I'm using Asana + Google Calendar but it's really not enough, for example I cannot schedule multiple project on the calendar and so no overview on it...

What tool do you use? Any suggestion?

Thank you guys :)

Comment: Google calendar works really well for multiple projects... I use it with mulitple calendars/projects and any chargeable time I add to calendar automagically goes into my invoicing system as well, so it almost covers everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a self hosted solution called 'Freelancer Office' that does similar tasks, I'm sure there will be others out there. You list an item and can then add that item to an invoice. It's a good all in one solution however it would be another system to back up and maintain and you obviously have a hosting cost attached.

Link to the system I referenced:

https://codecanyon.net/item/freelancer-office/8870728?s_rank=1

Comment: This is awesome!!! All the feature I asked!!! And also at the best cost ever! Should make a monument to the author.

Comment: Also other options on the site are evaluable.

Comment: I want to precise that after some months of use of the specific tool I'm back to Google Cal and Asana

Answer (score 2):

Google Calendar, Google Spreadsheet and Google Drive are great for these tasks, are free and accessible from desktop and apps anywhere anytime.

Comment: `<sarcasm>` And let Google track your business as well :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, by the way that's an amateur solution compared to professional others we can find on the web like Scoro, Humanity, etc!